# display files contents in textarea immediately after uploading

Tags: java, jquery, spring, file, jsp

I would like to display the content of csv file in a textarea for my project using jsp, java spring. 
I am uploading csv file which consist of user details . After uploading file i want to display content of this into textarea immediately.

[image]
Any code or how to do it.

P.S.: I really appreciate if anybody can edit or improve tags.

Comment: When you say immediately after loading what do you mean? Should the csv file be uploaded and processed on the server side and the user be redirected to this page? Or do you want this done asynchronously?

Comment: @bennettweb: I want to send file asynchronously to server side and perform some operation and then display processing output on same jsp page text area. How can send file asynchronously to server side. I am new to AJAX framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may wanna use jquery and jquery plugin [uplodify](http://www.uploadify.com). You will echo the uploaded file in your servlet or whatever. then push that "response" data into your html element...

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
  // your configuration...
  'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
     $('#yourhtmlelement').html('the contents of the file=' + response);
   }
});
```